# Is this condition checking if the error is a HASH and has arguments perl?

Tags: perl, if-statement, conditional-statements

Okay this is just a simple question on conditional statements, I just want to make sure my condition is true and not just executing because I have the wrong syntax or I'm not testing properly.

```
# Method for creating error message
sub new {
    my ( $class, $error, %args ) = @_;
    # Initialize error with data
    my $self = $error;
    # If the error contains context parameters... Insert parameters into string template
    if('HASH' && %args) {
        foreach my $key (@{ $self->{context} } ) {
            # And take the ones we need
            $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};
       }
        my @template_args = map { $self->{args}->{$_} } @{ $self->{context} };

        # map/insert arguments into context hash and insert into string template
        $self->{message} = sprintf ($self->{template}, @template_args);
    }
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

This is  what I was doing but it caused my build to fail:

```
if($self eq 'HASH' && %args) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Actually seeing this now, it looks wrong, as I am comparing self to HASH and %args

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `ref` in your original condition.

> ```
> $self eq 'HASH' && %args
> ```

Will check if `$self` is the string `'HASH'`. That's likely not what you wanted. You want to check the [reference type](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) of `$self`, so you have to do:

```
ref $self eq 'HASH' && %args
```

Now it will check the type of the reference and return true if that is `HASH`.

---

What you have in the full program code is definitely not what you wanted.

> ```
> 'HASH' && %args
> ```

The string `'HASH'` is always true. `%args` will return the number of elements of `%args` because it's scalar context, so it will be true if the hash has anything in it.